# Tool Strip Menu Items Events not getting triggered

Tags: c#, .net, labview

Hi I would like to describe what I am doing and what is my problem.

I am using ToolStrip Menu which has the menu Items like this

Item1

Item2

Item3

Item4

And I am using an item click event to know which Item I have clicked.

Now I want to change the menu such that few items might have sub Items.

Item1

Item2

Item3

Item4 >> SubItem1

```
        SubItem2
        SubItem3
```

Here comes the problem, I am Directly adding the sub items using the constructor. But when I click on this events are not getting triggered. But when I click on Item4 Event is getting triggered. But when I click on SubItems nothing is happening. Should I do any thing while adding the subItems.

Lastly, I am loading that .net control in labview.

Comment: Show us the code you are using.  Yes, you should do something when adding subitems:  you need to add an event handler to them.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTMbT.png

I am using the above code to add the items. All the main items are getting triggered in the item clicked event. Can you give us the sample code for what has to be done after adding the Subitems in drop down.

Comment: [Code I am using][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTMbT.png

I am using the above code to add the items. All the main items are getting triggered in the item clicked event. Can you give us the sample code for what has to be done after adding the Subitems in drop down.

Comment: Show your code: How did you register for Item4 events? How do you handle Item4 events?